# The type or namespace name 'File' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a script that will open a CSV file on Visual Studio using C# but when I reference the File class the error will pop up:

```
The type or namespace name 'File' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO'
```

I've made sure that I'm `using System` as well as `using System.IO` and went to add references for `System.dll` and `System.IO.dll` but when I do try and add them I get the error:

```
A reference to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.dll' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.
```

Same error for System.IO.dll.

I'm using .NETFramework v4.6 and Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: not sure on the actual cause of the error but you don't need to add references for System.dll and System.IO.dll, they're included by default in a new project. the using statements should've been enough

Comment: Use the correct project template to use this class.  Classic desktop, not a Store or Universal project.

Comment: Start a new Windows Desktop project (WinForms/WPF/Console/Class Library....) and see if the error persists. If not, port your current project to a new project.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, that might be why. I'm using Universal. I created a new project for WPF Application in Classic Desktop and it now works. Could you submit an answer for it so I can select it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This component is already automatically referenced by the build system

This message is particular to the kind of project templates that do not support the File class.  Windows Store, Phone or Universal.  You have to jump through more hoops when you target them, manipulating the file system is vetted by the runtime broker that ensures you are poking around in places you are allowed to look.  And it must always be done with async code on the theory that it might be slow.

The [Windows.Storage.StorageFile class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) is roughly similar.